# Is there a non-UART python transfer protocol layer to work with 512byte packets or less for BLE?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, network-protocols

I'm on a team working on a non-profit, open-source project and we're creating a web-based configuration tool to control a piece of custom hardware on a Raspberry Pi, using the ["Web Bluetooth API"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API).

Packets over the BLE connection are limited to 512 bytes, so we seem to need a transfer protocol layer to assist communication with the Pi.

We do not want a UART implementation, as we want transmission guarantees.

Does such a transfer protocol layer exist, ideally implemented in Python?

Or is there a simple way to generate a python implementation of a transfer protocol layer, that would work with 512byte packages?

Comment: A UART is a hardware device and unrelated to Bluetooth LE.

Comment: I assume you are talking about uart simulation implementation which uses notifications and writeWithoutResponse. Such impllementation does not provide guarantee indeed. But you can replace writeWithoutResp with WriteWithResponse and replace notifications with Indications - it will give control and guarantees back to you. Just use some new servivce or characteristic uuid to avoid confusion and problems with interoperability.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little too broad to be able to give any kind of specifics.

The official profiles that are available with Bluetooth are documented at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/

Custom services can be created fairly easily if you have control over both ends of the Bluetooth link. The [Nordic UART Service](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/10567/what-is-nus-nordic-uart-service) is one that appears to be quite common and there are various apps around that understand it to make testing of your peripheral easier.

Creating a custom service that minimises the amount of data sent over the Bluetooth link is usually the goal. There are various [guides](https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/) around that can help.

One of the better guides for creating a Bluetooth Peripheral with BlueZ and Python, is this one https://punchthrough.com/creating-a-ble-peripheral-with-bluez/

There are also Python [examples in the BlueZ source tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test)

And for completeness the BlueZ API's are documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc